# pdfViewer Angular

Tags: angular2, angular

Возникла проблема с отображением pdf документа на angular.

Делал по этим туториалам:
[medium.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyiel.png)
[npmjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXNzm.png)

Ошибка:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute 
'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.
Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch 
could not be cloned.
```

Нашел несколько ответов на github, единственным, кажется решением было использование angular + electron. Можно ли обойтись без этой связки? И почему возникает данная ошибка?

**pdf-viewer.component.html**

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block"></pdf-viewer>
```

**pdf-viewer.component.ts**

```
export class PdfViewerComp implements OnInit {

  pdfSrc: string = 'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**Снимок ошибки:**

[image: Стек трейс ошибки]

[image: Стек трейс ошибки со страницей]

**AppModule:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormUploadComponent } from './form-upload/form-upload.component';
import { DocumentService} from './service/document.service';
import { FormClassService} from './service/fromclass.service';
import { TypeDocService} from './service/typedoc.service';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { ListDocumentComponent } from './list-document/list-document.component';
import { FormEditComponent } from './form-edit/form-edit.component';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
import { PdfViewerComp } from './pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FormUploadComponent,
    ListDocumentComponent,
    FormEditComponent,
    PdfViewerComp
  ],
  imports: [
    routing,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
  ],
  providers: [DocumentService, FormClassService, TypeDocService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppRouting:**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormEditComponent } from './form-edit/form-edit.component';
import { FormUploadComponent } from './form-upload/form-upload.component';
import { ListDocumentComponent } from './list-document/list-document.component';
import { PdfViewerComp } from './pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: 'list-document', component: ListDocumentComponent },
    { path: '', component: ListDocumentComponent},
    { path: 'edit-document', component: FormEditComponent },
    { path: 'upload-document', component: FormUploadComponent },
    { path: 'pdf-view', component: PdfViewerComp }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: при каких обстоятельствах возникает ошибка? потому что в данный момент это гадание на кофейной гуще, я установил у себя - 0 ошибок

Comment: Возникает ошибка при подгрузке представления компонента с данным тегом.

<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block"></pdf-viewer>

В компоненте pdfSrc присвоена эта ссылка:
https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/pdf-test.pdf

Так же при загрузке перед этой ошибкой получаю:

GET https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/pdf-test.pdf net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Но эти ошибки, на сколько мне известно никак не связаны между собой.

Comment: `https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf` вот рабочая ссылка

Comment: @overthesanity , получаю ту же ошибку.) Можно как-то отдебажить или отследить источник? Полный стек трейс в шапке темы.

Comment: лучше бы вы приложили скриншоты кода и браузера с консолью открытой

Comment: @overthesanity , страница совершенно пуста, приложил скриншот с консолью и код.

Comment: "Решено" ставится зелёной галочкой возле ответа, а не в заголовке

Comment: @andreymal , через двадцать часов поставлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решено**

AdBlock блокировал подгрузку PDF файла.